# Regular Expression: numbers with specific amount of digits in specific order in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a `business.id` column in a data frame called `total_pop` that contains only number that contain anywhere between 1 and 4 digits. I'm trying to extract the numbers that only contain 4 digits AND ALSO begin with "13".

Sample Data:

```
sex   age    business.id
-------------------------
1     23     13
1     36     465
2     42     1309
1     19     1375
2     38     137
```

Desired Result:

```
sex   age    business.id
-------------------------
2     42     1309
1     19     1375
```

I've tried: `grep("{4}^[1][3]",total_pop$business.id,value=T)` but it returns numbers with any amount of digits starting with 13. So it returns 136 and 13.

Comment: you could also standardize the IDs such that they all have 4 characters (padded with 0s) and just grep for `^13`: `grep('^13', sprintf('%04s', total_pop$business.id), value = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this numerically:

```
df[df$business.id >= 1000 & floor(df$business.id / 100) == 13, ]

sex age business.id
3   2  42        1309
4   1  19        1375
```

If you wanted to handle this using `business.id` as a string, then we could use `grepl`:

```
df[grepl("^13\\d{2}$", df$business.id), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** nchar counts the number of characters and substr extracts the first two characters.

```
subset(total_pop, nchar(business.id) == 4 & substr(business.id, 1, 2) == 13)
##   sex age business.id
## 3   2  42        1309
## 4   1  19        1375
```

**2)** We can use a regular expression to grep out the values of interest.  ^ matches the start of the business.id, .. match any two characters and $ matches the end.

```
subset(total_pop, grepl("^13..$", business.id))
##   sex age business.id
## 3   2  42        1309
## 4   1  19        1375
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
total_pop <- structure(list(sex = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), age = c(23L, 36L, 
42L, 19L, 38L), business.id = c(13L, 465L, 1309L, 1375L, 137L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~sex, ~age, ~business.id,
  1L,  23L,          13L,
  1L,  36L,         465L,
  2L,  42L,        1309L,
  1L,  19L,        1375L,
  2L,  38L,         137L
)
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(business.id, "13\\d{2}"))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>     sex   age business.id
#>   <int> <int>       <int>
#> 1     2    42        1309
#> 2     1    19        1375
```